# How to set the spinner default to a string fetched from another screen

Tags: android, android-spinner

What I'm trying to do is, I'm asking user to select a value from a list view, after which he is redirected to another screen having a spinner with default as selected by the user . I've read quite a few posts on spinner's default but none of then included fetching info from another screen, I've tried them anyway but they didn't work.

This is how I pass the string from WorkEntryScreenActivity.java

```
//inside onCreate
mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> myAdapter, View myView, 
                        int myItemInt, long mylng) {
                  selectedFromList = (String) (mListView.getItemAtPosition(myItemInt));
                  top10 = true;
                  call(top10);  }

            });


//outside onCreate
protected void call(boolean top10){
    if(top10) {
    Intent i = new Intent(this, WorkEntryActivity.class);   
        i.putExtra("FromTab", "true");
        i.putExtra("workRequest",selectedFromList);
        startActivity(i);
        finish();
    }
   }
```

In the other java file WorkEntryActivity.java

```
//get the string
workRequestFetched = extras.getString("workRequest");

//This is where I need help
ArrayList<String> workRequestAdded = new ArrayList<String>();
        workRequestSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.workRequestSpinner);

        if(workRequestFetched != null){

            workRequestAdded.add(workRequestFetched);
        }

        ArrayList<String> workRequests = ServiceCall.workRequests;

        workRequestAdded.addAll(workRequests);

        final ArrayAdapter<String> workRequestAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,
                 workRequestAdded);

        workRequestAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);


        workRequestSpinner.setAdapter(workRequestAdapter);
```

Comment: Well I kept editing the code and it finally worked! Thank you for all your help. The above code works just fine now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I remember correctly, the spinner's default option is the first option in the String array associated with it. If you make workRequest the first option in the string array, it should be the default option.

EDIT: After some googling it seems that you cannot modify your res/Strings.xml programmatically. However I would be surprised if there isn't a way to link a String array defined in your relevant java file to your spinner.

Comment: we can set the devault view of the string from arrays.xml in android refer the below link for clarification http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12628348/android-spinner-setting-value-when-re

Answer (score 2):

First you have have to iterate through the `myAdap` adapter, using `myAdap.getItem(position)`, and find out which string in the adapter item matches with the string `workRequest`. Once you are able to fetch that item then you can set the default selection using `workRequestSpinner.setSelection(THE_POSITION_OF_MATCHED_STRING)`.

Hope the answer is helpful to you.

Comment: Oh I though of this, this wouldn't necessarily work because String workRequest may not be in the spinner's array list.

Comment: It won't work in that case.  You cannot set the spinner to a value that is not defined in the data supplied to it.

Comment: As described in the solution first iterate, if the String object is not found then using `myAdap.add(workRequest)`followed by the `workRequestSpinner.setSelection(myAdap.getPosition(workRequest))` should solve your problem.

Comment: Can I not just add the String workRequest irrespective of if the object is found in the array list or not, like I have? I've edited it please check.

Comment: You can surely add the object but how will that resolve the issue of setting the newly added String as the default selection? For that you will have to use `workRequestSpinner.setSelection(workRequestAdded.indexOf(workRequest))`.

Comment: @Harsh I am a little confused as to how did the answer you accepted and your code solve the problem you have stated? As in there is no place where you are setting the default selection for the spinner.

Comment: @ArunGeorge Actually, what I did is added the workRequest string to the ArrayList as the first element and then added rest of the elements to the list. That way when the user is redirected to the new screen spinner default shows the string value selected by the user.