# Android Spinner setting value when re

Tags: android, android-spinner

```
 <Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
    android:entries="@array/categorylist"
    android:prompt="@string/category" />
```

i have created spinner in the above format!

```
final Spinner spnr= (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    String category=spnr.getSelectedItem().toString();
```

pushed the spinner values in db by getting value in above format.

now when values retrieved from db. the spinner should set according to specific value...
how can i implement any ideas pls??

Comment: does you mean how would you explicitly be showing a particualr item to be one already selected rather than the first one(default one)

Comment: @Arpit Garg. Yes it should show particular spinner item selected when retrieved from db

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That can be possible only when you store the array of the items that are set as entries of Spinner. You can set the position of the selected item in spinner. So you have to find out index of the item that you query from the database. Load the StringArray of categorylist and iterate the array and compare each item with the item  fetched from the database. Then set the index of the found item as selected item in spinner.

```
    String[] list = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.categorylist);
    int index = 0;
    for(String item : list) {
        if(item.equals("your_item")){
            break;
        }
        index++;
    }
    spinner.setSelection(index);
```

Comment: Okay then load the string array and findout the item index. Like above   code.

Comment: Or else you can do like, instead of storing the string item in database you can save the index of the item. While you retrieve from the database set the same index as selected item of your spinner.

Comment: For my problem also it's working fine. Thanks you so much for providing the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Well by using **setSelection()** you can set particular selection for the spinner rather than the first one (by default).
Now your question would be how to get position from the value that you have.
So here is the code to do that:

```
String yourString = "some value"; //the value you want the position for

ArrayAdapter yourAdap = (ArrayAdapter) mySpinner.getAdapter(); //cast to an ArrayAdapter

int spinnerPosition = yourAdap.getPosition(yourString);

//set the default according to value
spnr.setSelection(spinnerPosition);
```

Comment: i have not used any array adapter for my spinner! i have saved spinner values in array.xml file

Comment: so what;s the big deal... you can find the index of item depending upon the value it contains